# BPMN 2.0, wouldn't a conditional even that never triggers 'hang' the system?

Tags: events, conditional-statements, bpmn

BPMN 2.0: Not sure I understand conditional events properly. For instance, wouldn't a conditional even that never triggers 'hang' the system?

I found this example below which triggered the question. thanks!

[image]

Comment: No. While waiting for the oven to heat you can wash dishes, set table, etc. After an hour you realize that the oven is broken and the event will nnever trigger, but there was no reason to hang around and watch during that time.

Comment: but still, if the oven never gets to 180 the condition is never met. Wondering of exits on these cases